# Verify at least one option has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, development-environment

I want to alert the user if no option in the form has been selected. My attempt is shown below, but whether an option is selected or not, the alert is still issued.

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="England">England<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Scotland">Scotland<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Wales">Wales<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland<br/>

    <!--radio buttons with different values-->

    <br/>2: Which of the following is not in London:<br/>
    <select id="answer2">
      <option value="St Paul's Cathedral">St Paul's Cathedral</option>
      <option value="Buckingham Palace">Buckingham Palace</option>
      <option value="Stonehenge">Stonehenge</option>
    </select>
```

```js
function getValue(qArray) {
    // get value from radio array
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
        if (qArray[i].checked) return qArray[i].value;
    }
    return "";
}

function validateForm() {
    var qArray = document.getElementsByName("mainForm");
    var formValid = false;
    var j = 0;
    while (!formValid && j < qArray.length) {
        if (qArray[j].checked) formValid = true;
        j++;        
    }

    if (!formValid) 
        alert("Must check some option!");
    return formValid;
}
```

Comment: You should start yourself and ask if you have something more specific than writing you the code

Comment: You valid it. What is the problem?

Comment: Help is appreciated as it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

I see you included jQuery in your tag, but aren't actually using jQuery.

Here is a solution without jQuery.

Get rid of the onsubmit in your form

```
 <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
```

And add a button to the end of your form

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit">
```

Then bind the new button to the event (instead of binding the form to the event)

```
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", validateForm, false);
```

And finally, in your validateForm function, the array should check the radio buttons, not the form. So change this line

```
    var qArray = document.getElementsByName("answer1");
```

Here is the final HTML

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="England"> England
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Scotland">Scotland
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Wales">Wales
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland
    <br/>

    <!--radio buttons with different values-->

    <br/>2: Which of the following is not in London:
    <br/>
    <select id="answer2">
        <option value="St Paul's Cathedral">St Paul's Cathedral</option>
        <option value="Buckingham Palace">Buckingham Palace</option>
        <option value="Stonehenge">Stonehenge</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit">
</form>
```

And your final JavaScript

document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", validateForm, false);

```
function getValue(qArray) {
    // get value from radio array
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
        if (qArray[i].checked) return qArray[i].value;
    }
    return "";
}

function validateForm() {
    var qArray = document.getElementsByName("answer1");
    var formValid = false;
    var j = 0;
    while (!formValid && j < qArray.length) {
        if (qArray[j].checked) 
            formValid = true;

        j++;        
    }

    if (!formValid) 
        alert("Must check some option!");
    return formValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here. Make this changes:

HTML:

```
   <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="POST">       
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="England">England<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Scotland">Scotland<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Wales">Wales<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland<br/>

      <!--radio buttons with different values-->

      <br/>2: Which of the following is not in London:<br/>
      <select id="answer2">
        <option value="St Paul's Cathedral">St Paul's Cathedral</option>
        <option value="Buckingham Palace">Buckingham Palace</option>
        <option value="Stonehenge">Stonehenge</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <input type="button" value='go' onclick="validateForm()"/>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
function validateRadio(radios) {
    // get value from radio array
    var i;   
    for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function validateForm() {

    var radios = document.getElementsByName("answer1");  
    var isFormValid = validateRadio(radios);
     alert(isFormValid);
    if(isFormValid) {       
      document.forms[0].submit();
      alert('form submitted!');
      }
      else
      {
        alert('You must select one location, please.');
      }     
}
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/q5rf4uf5/1/

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to be consistent on naming your elements. 'name="answer2"' must be added to your  element.
2. document.getElementsByName("mainForm") will only give 1 element (the ).  I would suggest using 'document.forms.mainForm' or document.forms["mainForm"].
3. you can traverse to all elements in the forms by using 'document.forms.mainForm.elements', but creating answer array would be simpler and

   4. add an empty  in your  just to make sure they select an answer instead of selecting default.

```js
function validateForm() {

  var answers = ["answer1","answer2"];
  var form = document.forms["mainForm"];
  var allValid=true;
  
  for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++){
 var answer = answers[i];
 if( form[answer].value.length==0){
   allValid=false;
   break;
 }
  }
  
  if(!allValid)
  alert("answer all questions");
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="England">England<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Scotland">Scotland<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Wales">Wales<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland<br/>

    <!--radio buttons with different values-->

    <br/>2: Which of the following is not in London:<br/>
    <select id="answer2" name="answer2" >
      <option value="">Select an answer</option>
      <option value="St Paul's Cathedral">St Paul's Cathedral</option>
      <option value="Buckingham Palace">Buckingham Palace</option>
      <option value="Stonehenge">Stonehenge</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```